# Running separate timers for different opened web pages in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am making a chrome extension where I need to keep record of time spent on different web pages.
I want timer to stop if some webpage is closed after bit of usage and start timer again from it's previously saved value if web page is reopened.

I am totally new to chrome extensions. Can anyone please guide a bit on this.

--
Thanks

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I have already gone through that tutorial and developed a working prototype as well, I am specifically stuck at keeping record of time spent on different web pages.

Comment: use events such as page load and unload ... record times etc in some storage that is available to you in a web extension ..

Comment: Quid pro quo Clarice

Comment: You can use a Map or dictionary of timers in the persistent background page, its key would be the tab id which is provided in the parameter of chrome.tabs.onActivated listener, see examples and documentation.

Comment: No, I can't help because I believe this is something you should research yourself.